# Does LED pulse like a strobe

Tags: optics, light-emitting-diodes

While my grandson was playing with his bayblades and it was spinning we shined a LED flashlight at it. To our amazement the motion seemed to stop or slow down. It would only do this on low beam. Does a LED light pulse like a strobe?

Comment: It could be they use pulse-width modulation for control - much more linear.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the way the brightness of an LED is controlled is not by changing the voltage across it but rather by pulsing it in what is called pulse width modulation.  There is a duty cycle with a frequency that could be as low as 50 Hz or up around 20 kHz.  The brightness of the LED is controlled by having turned on at full power for part of the cycle and off for the rest of it.  The fraction of time it's on for determines the brightness.

Here are a few related web pages

- [Controlling LED Brightness using PWM](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Controlling_LED_brightness_using_PWM)
- [How to choose right PWM frequency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79373/how-to-choose-right-pwm-frequency-for-led)